# Got error message „files: Hit reconnection limit“ in radius.log

Tags: freeradius

I am, using FreeRadius v3.0.13 for a while. Starting yesterday I  receive the a error message and some users unable to authenticate.

```sh
$ radiusd -v
radiusd: FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.13, for host x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, built on Apr 26 2019 at 09:30:22
FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.13
```

```sh
$ tail -f /var/log/radius/radius.log | grep reconnection\ limit
Wed Sep  4 15:26:52 2019 : Auth: (814) Login incorrect (files: Hit reconnection limit): [ut5000@example.org] (from client t5000 port 132416 cli 192.168.0.1)
```

The radius server uses LDAP for authorization (group membership) and authentication (user id / password).

Further investigation has shown that the issue seams to be related to the number of members in the authorization-LDAP-group. At Monday was one new member added and today one was removed – this resolved the issue.

What drives the error message or which config value is affecting the error?

A search in the source code was not helpful. The message is shown in the module `rlm_sql` but this is not used in my setup. I would expect it is driven from the module `rlm_files` according to the message itself.

Any help is welcome, thanks

Below are a traces done with `raddebug -u ut5000@example.org` and filtered for one request (`grep -E '^\(30065\)' trace-radius.out`)

```
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug: Received Access-Request Id 194 from 192.168.0.135:60602 to 192.168.0.5:1812 length 287
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:   User-Name = "ut5000@example.org"
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:   User-Password = "********"
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:   NAS-Port = 19501056
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:   Called-Station-Id = "192.168.0.135"
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:   Calling-Station-Id = "192.168.2.200"
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:   NAS-Port-Type = Virtual
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:   Tunnel-Client-Endpoint:0 = "192.168.2.200"
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:   NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.0.135
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:   Cisco-AVPair = "audit-session-id=c065c501012880005d776714"
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:   Cisco-AVPair = "ip:source-ip=192.168.2.200"
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:   CPVN3000-Tunnel-Group = "sslVPN-tunnel"
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:   ASA-ClientType = AnyConnect-Client-SSL-VPN
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:   Cisco-AVPair = "coa-push=true"
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug: # Executing section authorize from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/example
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:   authorize {
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:     policy filter_username {
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:       if (&User-Name) {
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:       if (&User-Name)  -> TRUE
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:       if (&User-Name)  {
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:         if (&User-Name =~ / /) {
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:         if (&User-Name =~ / /)  -> FALSE
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ ) {
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ )  -> FALSE
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ ) {
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ )  -> FALSE
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))  {
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))   -> FALSE
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)  {
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)   -> FALSE
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)  {
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)   -> FALSE
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:       } # if (&User-Name)  = notfound
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:     } # policy filter_username = notfound
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:     [preprocess] = ok
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug: suffix: Checking for suffix after "@"
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug: suffix: Looking up realm "example.org" for User-Name = "ut5000@example.org"
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug: suffix: No such realm "example.org"
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug:     [suffix] = noop
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug: files: Searching for user in group "cn=Mgmt-VPN,ou=memberlist,ou=groups,o=example.com"
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug: files: EXPAND (mail=%{%{Stripped-User-Name}:-%{User-Name}})
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug: files:    --> (mail=ut5000@example.org)
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug: files: Performing search in "ou=users,o=example.com" with filter "(mail=ut5000@example.org)", scope "sub"
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug: files: Waiting for search result...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug: files: User object found at DN "uid=ZZ00BM043,ou=users,o=example.com"
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug: files: Checking for user in group objects
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug: files:   EXPAND (uniquemember=%{control:Ldap-UserDN})
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug: files:      --> (uniquemember=uid\3dZZ00BM043\2cou\3dusers\2co\3dexample.com)
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug: files:   Performing search in "cn=Mgmt-VPN,ou=memberlist,ou=groups,o=example.com" with filter "(uniquemember=uid\3dZZ00BM043\2cou\3dusers\2co\3dexample.com)", scope "base"
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:20 2019: Debug: files:   Waiting for search result...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:22 2019: WARNING: files:   Search failed: Can't contact LDAP server. Got new socket, retrying...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:22 2019: Debug: files:   Waiting for search result...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:24 2019: WARNING: files:   Search failed: Can't contact LDAP server. Got new socket, retrying...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:24 2019: Debug: files:   Waiting for search result...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:26 2019: WARNING: files:   Search failed: Can't contact LDAP server. Got new socket, retrying...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:26 2019: Debug: files:   Waiting for search result...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:27 2019: WARNING: files:   Search failed: Can't contact LDAP server. Got new socket, retrying...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:27 2019: Debug: files:   Waiting for search result...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:29 2019: WARNING: files:   Search failed: Can't contact LDAP server. Got new socket, retrying...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:29 2019: Debug: files:   Waiting for search result...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:31 2019: WARNING: files:   Search failed: Can't contact LDAP server. Got new socket, retrying...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:31 2019: Debug: files:   Waiting for search result...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:34 2019: WARNING: files:   Search failed: Can't contact LDAP server. Got new socket, retrying...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:34 2019: Debug: files:   Waiting for search result...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:37 2019: WARNING: files:   Search failed: Can't contact LDAP server. Got new socket, retrying...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:37 2019: Debug: files:   Waiting for search result...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:39 2019: WARNING: files:   Search failed: Can't contact LDAP server. Got new socket, retrying...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:39 2019: Debug: files:   Waiting for search result...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:41 2019: WARNING: files:   Search failed: Can't contact LDAP server. Got new socket, retrying...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:41 2019: Debug: files:   Waiting for search result...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:42 2019: WARNING: files:   Search failed: Can't contact LDAP server. Got new socket, retrying...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:42 2019: Debug: files:   Waiting for search result...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:44 2019: WARNING: files:   Search failed: Can't contact LDAP server. Got new socket, retrying...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:44 2019: Debug: files:   Waiting for search result...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:47 2019: WARNING: files:   Search failed: Can't contact LDAP server. Got new socket, retrying...
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:47 2019: ERROR: files:   Hit reconnection limit
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:47 2019: Debug: files: User is not a member of "cn=Mgmt-VPN,ou=memberlist,ou=groups,o=example.com"
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:47 2019: Debug:     [files] = noop
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:47 2019: Debug:     [expiration] = noop
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:47 2019: Debug:     [logintime] = noop
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:47 2019: WARNING: pap: No "known good" password found for the user.  Not setting Auth-Type
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:47 2019: WARNING: pap: Authentication will fail unless a "known good" password is available
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:47 2019: Debug:     [pap] = noop
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:47 2019: Debug:   } # authorize = ok
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:47 2019: ERROR: No Auth-Type found: rejecting the user via Post-Auth-Type = Reject
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:47 2019: Debug: Failed to authenticate the user
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:47 2019: Debug: Using Post-Auth-Type Reject
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:47 2019: Debug: # Executing group from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/example
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:47 2019: Debug:   Post-Auth-Type REJECT {
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:47 2019: Debug: attr_filter.access_reject: EXPAND %{User-Name}
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:47 2019: Debug: attr_filter.access_reject:    --> ut5000@example.org
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:47 2019: Debug: attr_filter.access_reject: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 11
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:47 2019: Debug:     [attr_filter.access_reject] = updated
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:47 2019: Debug:   } # Post-Auth-Type REJECT = updated
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:47 2019: Debug: Delaying response for 1.000000 seconds
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:58 2019: Debug: Sending delayed response
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:58 2019: Debug: Sent Access-Reject Id 194 from 192.168.0.5:1812 to 192.168.0.135:60602 length 20
(30065) Tue Sep 10 11:04:58 2019: Debug: Cleaning up request packet ID 194 with timestamp +504084
```

In contrast the same user using another group (smaller) works.

```
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug: Received Access-Request Id 202 from 192.168.0.135:60602 to 192.168.0.5:1812 length 290
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:   User-Name = "ut5000@example.org"
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:   User-Password = "********"
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:   NAS-Port = 19533824
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:   Called-Station-Id = "192.168.0.135"
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:   Calling-Station-Id = "192.168.2.200"
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:   NAS-Port-Type = Virtual
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:   Tunnel-Client-Endpoint:0 = "192.168.2.200"
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:   NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.0.135
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:   Cisco-AVPair = "audit-session-id=c065c501012b00005d776d7b"
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:   Cisco-AVPair = "ip:source-ip=192.168.2.200"
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:   CPVN3000-Tunnel-Group = "sslVPN-ng-tunnel"
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:   ASA-ClientType = AnyConnect-Client-SSL-VPN
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:   Cisco-AVPair = "coa-push=true"
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug: # Executing section authorize from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/example
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:   authorize {
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:     policy filter_username {
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:       if (&User-Name) {
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:       if (&User-Name)  -> TRUE
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:       if (&User-Name)  {
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:         if (&User-Name =~ / /) {
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:         if (&User-Name =~ / /)  -> FALSE
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ ) {
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ )  -> FALSE
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ ) {
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ )  -> FALSE
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))  {
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))   -> FALSE
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)  {
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)   -> FALSE
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)  {
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)   -> FALSE
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:       } # if (&User-Name)  = notfound
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:     } # policy filter_username = notfound
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:     [preprocess] = ok
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug: suffix: Checking for suffix after "@"
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug: suffix: Looking up realm "example.org" for User-Name = "ut5000@example.org"
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug: suffix: No such realm "example.org"
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug:     [suffix] = noop
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug: files: Searching for user in group "cn=NG-SSL-VPN,ou=memberlist,ou=groups,o=example.org"
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug: files: EXPAND (mail=%{%{Stripped-User-Name}:-%{User-Name}})
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug: files:    --> (mail=ut5000@example.org)
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug: files: Performing search in "ou=users,o=example.org" with filter "(mail=ut5000@example.org)", scope "sub"
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:39 2019: Debug: files: Waiting for search result...
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug: files: User object found at DN "uid=ZZ00BM043,ou=users,o=example.org"
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug: files: Checking for user in group objects
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug: files:   EXPAND (uniquemember=%{control:Ldap-UserDN})
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug: files:      --> (uniquemember=uid\3dZZ00BM043\2cou\3dusers\2co\3dexample.org)
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug: files:   Performing search in "cn=NG-SSL-VPN,ou=memberlist,ou=groups,o=example.org" with filter "(uniquemember=uid\3dZZ00BM043\2cou\3dusers\2co\3dexample.org)", scope "base"
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug: files:   Waiting for search result...
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug: files: User found in group object "cn=NG-SSL-VPN,ou=memberlist,ou=groups,o=example.org"
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug: files: users: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 31
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug:     [files] = ok
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug:     [expiration] = noop
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug:     [logintime] = noop
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: WARNING: pap: No "known good" password found for the user.  Not setting Auth-Type
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: WARNING: pap: Authentication will fail unless a "known good" password is available
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug:     [pap] = noop
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug:   } # authorize = ok
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug: Found Auth-Type = users
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug: # Executing group from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/example
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug:   Auth-Type users {
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug: users: Login attempt by "ut5000@example.org"
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug: users: Using user DN from request "uid=ZZ00BM043,ou=users,o=example.org"
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug: users: Waiting for bind result...
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug: users: Bind successful
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug: users: Bind as user "uid=ZZ00BM043,ou=users,o=example.org" was successful
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug:     [users] = ok
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug:   } # Auth-Type users = ok
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug: # Executing section post-auth from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/example
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug:   post-auth {
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug:     update {
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug:       No attributes updated
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug:     } # update = noop
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug:     [exec] = noop
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug:   } # post-auth = noop
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug: Sent Access-Accept Id 202 from 192.168.0.5:1812 to 192.168.0.135:60602 length 0
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:40 2019: Debug: Finished request
(30151) Tue Sep 10 11:31:45 2019: Debug: Cleaning up request packet ID 202 with timestamp +505723
```

After spending some time to do ldapsearch and iptraces. It seems the issue is caused by an old load-balancer. One frame of the encrypted response is not proper handled.

**Background**
The LDAP server response with two answer to the query.

Example correct:

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <cn=NG-SSL-VPN,ou=memberlist,ou=groups,o=example.com> with scope baseObject
# filter: (uniquemember=uid\3dZZ00BM043\2cou\3dusers\2co\3dexample.com)
# requesting: ALL
#

# NG-SSL-VPN, memberlist, groups, example.com
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top
ou: memberlist
…

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

Example corrupted:

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <cn=Mgmt-VPN,ou=memberlist,ou=groups,o=example.com> with scope baseObject
# filter: (uniquemember=uid\3dZZ00BM043\2cou\3dusers\2co\3dexample.com)
# requesting: ALL
#

# Mgmt-VPN, memberlist, groups, example.com
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top
ou: memberlist
…

# numResponses: 1
# numEntries: 1
ldap_result: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

The first answer contains the member list for the group and the second is the search result. In case of the error the second record is destroyed in some way.

Comment: Run the server in debug mode ``radiusd -X`` and paste the output

Comment: @ArranCudbard-Bell Because the new test effected the LDAP server I have to wait until next week for the test.
However, to prevent „noise“, as I have it with `radius -X`, I prefer to use `raddebug -u  ut5000@example.org`. Is this acceptable?

Comment: Updated my question with my findings about the cause of the issue.